# Making sure settings are set before executing other logic in Chrome v3 extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

This is an example **background.js** of a **v3** chrome extension. I try to set the default settings of the extension during installation.

```
const settings = {
  enableContextMenu: true,
};

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(details => {
  if (details.reason === 'install') {
    chrome.storage.local.set(settings);
  }
});

chrome.storage.local
  .get(['enableContextMenu'])
  .then(({ enableContextMenu }) => {
    // enableContextMenu is undefined here
    if (enableContextMenu) {
      chrome.contextMenus.create({
        id: 'extension-contextmenu',
        title: 'Extension Menu',
        type: 'normal',
        contexts: ['link'],
      });
    }
  });
```

But how do I know the settings are set in onInstalled already so that I can continue adding a context menu by checking the **enableContextMenu** from storage? In this example, getting **enableContextMenu** is **undefined** although settings were supposed to be set in onInstalled listener, probably because of race condition.

What is the correct algorithm to initialize settings and execute other logic depending on settings?

Comment: with storage.*.get method you can use fallback values
So you can write: chrome.storage.local.get({'enableContextMenu': true})

Comment: @Robbi thank you, this is very neat. So I should set the settings in an onInstalled listener and always use fallback values if I need to get a setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a bad idea in general, but I still recommend using this syntax when you're not sure if the object has been initialized.
For user triggered events (I'm referring to chrome APIs like action.on*, omnibox.on*, command.on* etc) normally there is no need for this trick because when they fire you can be pretty sure that the parameters initialization is passed.
Different for other events such as "runtime.onMessage" and "runtime.onInstalled" whose activation is not always foreseeable in advance and therefore it is not easy to establish the code execution flow in general.
Certainly with the first "pass" the instructions of the main flow are executed first, both the synchronous and the asynchronous ones, after which it passes to any callback functions and lastly the chrome events are honored (at least I know it like this).
It's OK then to set the initial parameters to onInstalled because you're sure they won't be reinitialized a second time (which could be deleterious), but be aware that the onInstalled event handler certainly does NOT run first.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```js
const settings = {
  enableContextMenu: true,
};

const main = async () => {
  const result = await chrome.storage.local.get("enableContextMenu");
  console.log(result.enableContextMenu);
  if (!result.enableContextMenu) {
    chrome.storage.local.set(settings);
  }
}

main();
```

Comment: Thanks but why not directly set? like ```const result = await chrome.storage.local.set(settings);``` so there is no need to check conditionals too. The problem is the listener ````chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener```` do not get called after an await https://playcode.io/1492370